# Retrieving OS platform through SCCM/CMD/VBS

Tags: vbscript, cmd, platform, sccm

Scenario: I deploy software packages through SCCM and, sometimes, they run CMD files that control the installation as soon as they arrive in the machine.
For packages that are set to run in x86 and x64 machines, the condition is as follows:

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%i in ('CD') do set CurDir=%%i
cd "%CurDir%"
If Exist "C:\program files (x86)" goto X64
Msiexec /i "x86.msi"
:X64
Msiexec /i "x64.msi"
```

But due to some changes in our environment, that is not enough anymore. I found a way to retrieve this information through a vbs (which we use here as well), but I'm having trouble passing that value along

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")        

Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    msg = objOperatingSystem.OSArchitecture
Next
```

Is there anyway to "translate" that so I can conditionalize the CMD to run the right command for each platform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use `wmic os get OSArchitecture` in your batch script, but why? VBScript is far more versatile than batch could ever hope to be. You could simply [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the installers from VBScript. If anything you should move forward to PowerShell, not backward to batch.

Comment: Thanks, Ansgar! Actually, we are already studying an upgrade towards Powershell, but we distribute globally and PS versions are not yet standardized. That said, I would have to find a way to retrieve that information through the CMD only (as I do nowadays), since the vb scripts get invoked only during the MSI's ExecSequence...

Comment: Just as an additional idea (I would probably not do it myself, as imo pure vbs is far the most convenient option for sccm) to consider: you can also let sccm do the check. If you create two programs you could specify the environment to be exclusively 32bit on one and 64bit on the other.

Comment: I agree with you, Syberdoor, but for some obscure reason, CMD is the standard for SCCM here. In some cases, I create programs set to run in only one of the platforms (just as you said), but in the majority of the cases, I have to create a program that will install on BOTH, but will behave differently for each one, thus the need for that condition. Anyway, I think Hackoo's suggestion is going to settle it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
@echo off
wmic cpu get addresswidth | find "32" >nul  && echo system 32 bit || echo system 64 bit
pause
```

Comment: it works, thanks! I was able to put the other commands inside of the if/else clauses, and it seems to work in all of the machines/servers we currently use. I'll keep editing it and, should I find anything new, I'll post here!